# syntax problems with my script

Tags: jquery, syntax

this is the original script...

```
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    //Show and hide the Loading icon on Ajax start/end

    $j('.bwbps_uploadform').submit(function() { 
        $j('#bwbps_message').html('');
        bwbpsAjaxLoadImage(this);
        return false; 
    });

    //make sure the upload form radio button is on Select file
    $j(".init_radio").attr("checked","checked");
        //Add OnClick to the Mass Update Buttons in the PhotoSmash Settings form
        if ($j('#bwbps_gen_settingsform').val() == '1') {
            bwbpsAddPSSettingsMassUpdateActions();
        }
        $j('.bwbps-post-cat-form').attr('multiple','multiple');
    }   
});
```

I want to change this script to call it in another function, but there is a syntax error in firebug:

```
var myFunction;
$j(document).ready(function() { 
    //Show and hide the Loading icon on Ajax start/end
    myFunction = function() {
        $j('.bwbps_uploadform').submit(function() { 
            $j('#bwbps_message').html('');
            bwbpsAjaxLoadImage(this);
            return false; 
        });

        //make sure the upload form radio button is on Select file
        $j(".init_radio").attr("checked","checked");

        //Add OnClick to the Mass Update Buttons in the PhotoSmash Settings form
        if ($j('#bwbps_gen_settingsform').val() == '1') {
            bwbpsAddPSSettingsMassUpdateActions();
        }
        $j('.bwbps-post-cat-form').attr('multiple','multiple');
    }   
});
```

whats wrong? can anybody help me??

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: it should be `var j = $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: What is the error Firebug gives you

Comment: this is not the problem ^^ in code its: var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: I don't think this can be the problem, but you miss a semicolon on function closure.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
 var myFunction;
 $j(document).ready(function() { 
  //Show and hide the Loading icon on Ajax start/end
  myFunction = function($j) {
    $j('.bwbps_uploadform').submit(function() { 
        $j('#bwbps_message').html('');
        bwbpsAjaxLoadImage(this);
        return false; 
    });

    //make sure the upload form radio button is on Select file
    $j(".init_radio").attr("checked","checked");

    //Add OnClick to the Mass Update Buttons in the PhotoSmash Settings form
    if ($j('#bwbps_gen_settingsform').val() == '1') {
        bwbpsAddPSSettingsMassUpdateActions();
    }
    $j('.bwbps-post-cat-form').attr('multiple','multiple');
   }   
 });
```

Pass $j in the myFunction as an argument

Comment: the only thing I want is that I can call this function in another function ... or maybe there are simpler and better solutions for this?